# How to indentify which user profile is activated on Android Multi User feature?

Tags: android, android-multiple-users

Android has Multi Users feature:

[image]

I'd like to identify on my application on some part of the code which is the actual activated user. For example if the activated user is the First, Second or Guest.

Is there any way to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just found a way to identify the Main user (system user) the first one that was created on system.

```
UserManager um = (UserManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);
um.isSystemUser();
```

With that I can identify if the user is different of the system user.